# Run a shell script from a python script when a button is pressed

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, script

I'm trying to create a very simple python script that waits for a GPIO button press and then runs a shell script. I personally don't know much about python so what I've come up with is mostly from other sources with a similar issue.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.IN)

input = GPIO.input(16)

while True:
        inputValue = GPIO.input(16)
        if (inputValue == False):
                os.system("scan.sh")
```

So once the button on pin 16 is pressed, I need it to run the shell script "scan.sh". However when I run the python script it repeats

```
sh: 1: scan.sh: not found
```

and control+c won't end it. Nothing changes whether the button is pressed or not.
What do I need to change?

Comment: Try providing the full path to `scan.sh`?

Answer (score 3):

There are some points to look into / fix here:

1. How is the button connected?

   - Does the button pull the pin to GND when pressed and does the pin have an
     external pull-up resistor to 3.3 V connected?
     Because with `GPIO.input(16) == False` you are checking if the pin is low.
     If there is no pull-up resistor connected the pin will float and this
     expression would be true more often than you want it to be (this might be 
     the reason why your program tries to execute `scan.sh` without the button 
     being pressed). You can setup the BCM chip's internal pull-up resistor in 
     software with
     `GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)`
   - Is it really the BCM GPIO16 pin?
     With `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)` you are using the BCM chip's pin numbering.
     BCM GPIO16 [maps to](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=181315) pin 36 on the 40-pin header.
2. Run `scan.sh`only once when button is pressed.
   With checking `GPIO.input(16)` in the infinit loop you are polling the pin
   as fast as possible. So if the pin gets LOW, you are re-starting `scan.sh`
   really often until the pin gets HIGH. You could remember the last read state
   in a variable and execute `scan.sh` only if it was changed. But I would
   suggest to use the edge detection feature of the GPIO module. There are
   [different options to do this](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/). In the example below, an event is
   registered to detect a falling edge and execute a function if this happens.
3. Let your Python script find `scan.sh`.
   As mentioned in the other aswer by joan, with `os.system("scan.sh")` the
   Python script executes a file in the current working directory.
   Depending on how you start the Python script, this is not
   the directory where your Python script resides. So the best would be to give
   an absolute path to `scan.sh` like
   `os.system("/home/sam/myscripts/scan.sh")`
4. Make `scan.sh` executable.
   As also mentioned in the answer by joan, on linux you need to give
   permissions for a file to be executed.
   With `chmod +x /home/sam/myscripts/scan.sh` you will make your script
   executable.

So if your pin 36 (GPIO16) is connected to a button that pulls it to GND and your script is executable, than this should work:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os

# Define a callback function that will be called by the GPIO
# event system:
def onButton(channel):
    if channel == 16:
        os.system("/home/sam/myscripts/scan.sh")

# Setup GPIO16 as input with internal pull-up resistor to hold it HIGH
# until it is pulled down to GND by the connected button: 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# Register an edge detection event on FALLING edge. When this event
# fires, the callback onButton() will be executed. Because of
# bouncetime=20 all edges 20 ms after a first falling edge will be ignored: 
GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.FALLING, callback=onButton, bouncetime=20)

# The script would exit now but we want to wait for the event to occure
# so we block execution by waiting for keyboard input so every key will exit
# this script
input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Re `sh: 1: scan.sh: not found`

Either:

1. no file called scan.sh exists in the current working directory (of
   the script)
2. scan.sh does not have the executable bit set
3. the user has no permission to view scan.sh

I suppose 2. is the most likely.

To set the executable bit use the command `chmod +x scan.sh`