# Run gpio script from startup to listen for button press and then execute command and bash script

Tags: python, pitft, gpiozero

I have this python script that is intended to run from startup and listen for a buttonpress. If there is a buttonpress (held for 2s) the gpio script should run two bash scripts. The python script runs if it is done with `python /path/to/script/script.py` so I know it is working. If I try to run in from startup by a `crontab -e` `@reboot /path/to/script/script.py` I can see that it is active when running the `top` command. However, the button press will not fire the intended bash scripts. I have tried and modify `~/.bashrc` and tried to have a bash script in `crontab -e` with `sudo python /path/to/script.py`. None of them worked. To complicate things further, If I change it to call a command instead, like `killall -9 openvpn` for example... then it works.. what am I doing wrong?

The python script looks like the following

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause
import os
def runboth():
     os.system("/opt/script/script_a.sh")

     os.system("/opt/script/script_b.sh")


runboth_btn = Button(23, hold_time=2)
runboth_btn.when_held = runboth


pause()
```

`

Below is one bash script I try to run with the button press. Its located in `~/opt/script#` and has the permissions `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 240 Mar 21 11:58 match_email.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#run match
python /opt/tmp_email/email_match.py

wait
mv /opt/tmp_email/output.csv /opt/emailoutput$(date -d "today"+"%Y%m%d%H%M").csv
```

If I try to run it with a `subprocess.call` looking like

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause
import subprocess
def runboth():
    subprocess.call(['sh', '/opt/script/script_a.sh'], shell=False)

    subprocess.call(['sh', '/opt/script/script_b.sh'], shell=False)

runboth_btn = Button(17, hold_time=2)
runboth_btn.when_held = runboth


pause()
```

But didn´t work either..

Crontab looks like

```
@reboot /opt/script/run_both.py
```

I have had a look at [Run a shell script from a python script when a button is pressed](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76342/run-a-shell-script-from-a-python-script-when-a-button-is-pressed) but that didn´t help me.. 
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please show us at least one of the scripts? Along with the location of the scripts.

Comment: try running the scripts with this instead and see if it works: `import subprocess`  then call them with `subprocess.call(['sh', '/home/pi/Desktop/script/script_a.sh'], shell=False)`

Comment: Edited post with bash example and subprocess .. didn´t work unfortunatly..

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few things that might have gone wrong.

1. You are defining the location of the scripts with the "~/" notation, which only works if the same user that is running the python script is storing the scripts. I'd put the scripts in something like /opt/project_name/script_a.sh
2. The scripts might not be executable by the user that is running the python script.
3. You might not have the #!/bin/bash at the top of the shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here. As mentioned in this post, systemd is the most reliable. I had to laborate with what user I ran it with but otherwise quite straightforward.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=200174